# Blur image where the cursor is

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, mousehover

There's this cool effect that I'd like to reproduct, on the image when you hover it :
https://jonhopkins.co.uk/

I don't know how to do it at all I have to admit. It's not even a "blur" effect so that's why I'm so lost, but it doesn't matter if I can't do this a "wavy blur" will do the trick, maybe.
Any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: That "image" is actually a <canvas> element.

Comment: Ok that's why it's able to do weird things, I should ve check that